# Can Laravel 4 modules be extended by default (in-core-functionality) by other modules like in Drupal?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

E.g. in Drupal you have a module called **Views** and you need that module to run module called **Views Slideshow** (because it needs to use some methods from Views module controllers/models etc.) and you need these two to run **Views Slideshow Extra Effects** module (this module use stuff from all two previous and extends that in specific way etc.)

Those names of the modules are just made-up examples, I am not longer using Drupal, but I have very much liked its modules architecture.

So, can L4 offer me this kind of modules environment when I just copy a module with structure like (this structure is used in CodeIgniter's MX HMVC:

```
modules/
             views/
                 controllers/
                     views.php
                 models/
                     views_model.php
                 views/
                     display.php
             views_slideshow/
                 controllers/
                     views_slideshow.php
                 models/
                     views_slideshow_model.php
                 views/
                     display.php
             views_slideshow_extra_effects/
                 controllers/
                     views_slideshow_extra_effects.php
                 models/
                     views_slideshow_extra_effects_model.php
                 views/
                     display.php
```

And important question:
**Can all this be done without using composer and including my modules in some configuration files etc.?**

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you do not just use composer? This is exactly what it was designed to do - it will allow you to develop your own libraries/modules and 'plug' them straight into your Laravel 4 app with no changes to the core code etc.

Note - composer modules can be private libraries on your computer - they do not have to be uploaded to packagist.org to be used. I even store my private composer libraries in private github repos that are automatically pulled into my projects.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to laravel. That's why I am asking here. So, can it be done without using composer or not? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: You could edit the start/global.php file and add new directories to be autoloaded

Comment: With Composer and its class autoloading capabilities, you can create your own module type structure and register it with Composer. Laravel doesn't dictate that controllers need to exist in the controllers directory, or that models need to exist in the models directory. You could literally create a modules directory and organize it as you wish, as long as Composer can find your classes correctly.